# Can two hyper-v clusters access the same Lun

Tags: hyper-v, lun

Looking at setting up 2 Hyper-V cluster with 3 host server on each cluster and I was seeing how I need to carve out the LUN, which has 25 all flash disk array and 25 SAS drives in order to share this data across both cluster.

Answer (score 4):

> Can two Hyper-V clusters access the same LUN?

Can it?....yes, yes they can - terrible, awful idea however - almost instant filesystem corruption! loss of data! human sacrifice! dogs and cats living together! mass hysteria!

So yeah, don't.

Why have two clusters at all? And your array is highly-likely to be able to just bind all the disks together into one pool and then create LUNs of whatever sizes you need anyway.

Comment: Exactly this. Build one big storage pool, create logical disks (=LUNs).